# JSLint and ESLint Problems (Brackets)

Tags: node.js, json, eslint, jslint, nunjucks

I am creating a mock website for a small project that I am doing. I am using nunjucks to perform some tasks. When I try to create a .js file that I can run later, I am getting errors.

I have looked online, and tried every solution out there. I couldn't get any of them to work.

My Code:

```
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const fs = require('fs');  // The file system module

let files = ["index.html", "About.html", "Membership.html", "Fighting%20Kites.html"];
let srcDir = "./content/";
let outDir = "./output/";

// Tells nunjucks where to look for templates and set any options
nunjucks.configure('views', { autoescape: true });

for (let fname of files) {
let contents = fs.readFileSync(srcDir + fname);
let outString = nunjucks.render('base.njk', {mainContent: contents});
fs.writeFileSync(outDir + fname, outString);
console.log(`Wrote file: ${fname}`);
}
```

My Error Messages:

```
JSLint (2)
1   Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const'. const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
1   Stopping. (10% scanned).    const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

ESLint (1)
1   ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved   const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is a ES6 JavaScript feature. Try enabling the ES6 syntax for Eslint:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
    }
}
```

Comment: In `.eslintrc.json` in your project directory. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring